# svnsync can't start pre-revprop-change hook

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, svn-hooks, svnsync

I'm trying to use `svnsync`.
It works on one target server, but fails on another with very similar setup and I can't find what's different. The source server is the same in both cases so I guess it's setup is irrelevant.

Target server is: Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard SP1, 64 bit

SVN is: VisualSVN Server 2.5.9 (tried also 2.5.7 and 2.5.8)

**svnsync init** fails:

```
E:\>svnsync init https://.../ https://.../
svnsync: E175002: DAV request failed; it's possible that the repository's pre-revprop-change hook either failed or is non-existent
svnsync: E175008: At least one property change failed; repository is unchanged
svnsync: E175002: Error setting property 'svn:sync-lock': Failed to start '.../hooks/pre-revprop-change.bat' hook
```

Hook exists and contains just 1 line:

```
E:\>type ...\hooks\pre-revprop-change.bat
exit 0
```

(the same hook works on another target server)

Looking at Event Viewer in Windows I see the following errors in VisualSVN Server log:

```
Failed to start '.../hooks/pre-revprop-change.bat' hook  [500, #165001]
[client 2002:f8d:64d6::f8d:64d6]

Can't start process '.../hooks/pre-revprop-change.bat': Invalid argument  [500, #22]
[client 2002:f8d:64d6::f8d:64d6]
```

Version of svnsync used:

```
E:\>which svnsync
D:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnsync.EXE

E:\>svnsync --version
svnsync, version 1.7.9 (r1462340)
   compiled Apr  1 2013, 18:58:57

Copyright (C) 2013 The Apache Software Foundation.
This software consists of contributions made by many people; see the NOTICE file for more information.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.apache.org/

The following repository access (RA) modules are available:

* ra_neon : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV protocol using Neon.
  - handles 'http' scheme
  - handles 'https' scheme
* ra_svn : Module for accessing a repository using the svn network protocol.
  - handles 'svn' scheme
* ra_local : Module for accessing a repository on local disk.
  - handles 'file' scheme
* ra_serf : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV protocol using serf.
  - handles 'http' scheme
  - handles 'https' scheme
```

The question is - what the h*ll is wrong here? )))

Comment: 1. Did you test any other hooks (e.g. `pre-commit` or `post-commit`)? 2. Do they work or fail with the same error? What is the value of the global environment variable `%COMSPEC%` on the affected machine? 3. Under what account do you run VisualSVN Server service? 'Network Service' or a custom dedicated account?

Answer (score 0):

A reboot of destination server worked for me.